# Python - Unpivotting multiple columns into single column

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title suggest, I am trying to turn this

[image]

into this

[image]

The end-goal is ideally so that I'd be able to group-by them up and get a word count.

This is the code that I've tried so far. I am unsure.

```
df_unpivoted = final_df.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars= 'index', var_name = 'Count', value_name = 'Value')


df = final_df.rename(columns=lambda x: x + x[-1] if x.startswith('index') else x)
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['0'], i='id', j='i')
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```